# QDialog.done() not closing the QDialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qdialog

I have the following QDialog built with QT Designer and i'm trying to save some data from the fields to an sqlite database, and close the QDialog after that

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from DatabaseOperations import DatabaseOperations

class Ui_MaterialEdit(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, sqlite, material_id):
        super().__init__()
        self.material_id = material_id
        self.sqlite = sqlite
        self.database_operations = DatabaseOperations(sqlite)

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(460, 259)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Dialog)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 441, 241))
        self.groupBox.setTitle("")
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.code_lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.code_lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 251, 20))
        self.code_lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.save_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.save_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 200, 101, 23))
        self.save_btn.setObjectName("save_btn")

        self.save_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.saveMaterialData())
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)


    def saveMaterialData(self):
        material_code = self.code_lineEdit.text()
        self.database_operations.updateMaterial(self.material_id, material_code)
        self.done(1)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "تعديل المادة"))
        self.code_label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "الكود:"))
        self.save_btn.setText(_translate("Dialog", "حفظ"))
```

I want it to close after clicking `save_btn`. However, it doesn't. I already tried `self.done(1)`, `self.reject()`, `self.accept()`, `self.close()`. No errors are thrown, nevertheless, the QDialog doesn't close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by changing this

```
self.save_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.saveMaterialData())
```

to this

```
self.save_btn.clicked.connect(Dialog.accept)
self.save_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.saveMaterialData())
```